# Using bash to find file and duplicate with new name?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, music

I have a large music collection. Each album folder has an album art file called "album.jpg". Every music jukebox, streaming server and whatnot I have ever used has been able to parse the album art and display said art. I just added a Sonos system and it won't parse "album.jpg" it will only parse "folder.jpg".

I would like to use a bash script to find every instance of "album.jpg" in a hierarchical folder structure of Artist-->Album and duplicate the file in the same location and name it "folder.jpg". I'm having trouble with passing info from find to cp. I can't seem to the syntax right.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command: `find Music -name album.jpg -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' x; do cp "$x" "${x%/*}/folder.jpg"; done`

Details:

- `-print0`, `-r`, and `-d $'\0'` together ensure that paths that contain whitespace don't get mangled
- `${x%/*}` means remove the last `/` and everything that follows it from `$x` (e.g., `/foo/bar/album.jpg` becomes `/foo/bar`)

Comment: I used the command but I got an error. I recieved this error for the following folder.  cp: target 'Voltage/folder.jpg' is not a directory for /mnt/ext-hd/ACDC/High Voltage/. This was the kind of the same problem I was having before.

Comment: I forgot to add quotes around the cp arguments. Try what I have now.

Comment: Excellent! as Stephen the Mad Irishman would say!

Answer (score 0):

If the collection is stored on a Unix-style filesystem, I think I'd use symbolic links for something like this e.g.

```
find path/to/musicfolder -name 'album.jpg' -execdir ln -s {} ./folder.jpg \;
```